# Oracle 11GR2 - When will datafile autoextend?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Let's say I have a single datafile, DF1. After DF1 becomes 50% full, I add a new datafile DF2 of equal size. Both datafiles have autoextend set to ON. When file DF1 becomes full (and therefore, DF2 will be around 50% full), will it autoextend DF1 despite having free space in DF2? Or will it instead leave DF1 as is (100% full) and start allocating extents from DF2 only?

Here's a visualization

```
When I add new datafile:
DF1: xxxxxxx00000000
DF2: 000000000000000

After DF1 becomes full:
DF1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DF2: xxxxxxx00000000


Will it start to do this?

DF1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DF2: xxxxxxxxxxx0000

Or will it start to do this?

DF1: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
DF2: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Extents will spread evenly:

```
SQL> select * from v$version where rownum = 1;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create tablespace test datafile size 10M autoextend on next 10M maxsize 100M;

Tablespace created.

SQL> create table t1 (id number) tablespace test;

Table created.

SQL> alter table t1 allocate extent (size 50M);

Table altered.

SQL> select * from dba_tablespace_usage_metrics where tablespace_name = 'TEST';

TABLESPACE_NAME                USED_SPACE TABLESPACE_SIZE USED_PERCENT
------------------------------ ---------- --------------- ------------
TEST                                 6536           12800      51.0625

SQL> alter tablespace test add datafile size 10M autoextend on next 10M maxsize 100M;

Tablespace altered.

SQL> select file_id, sum(blocks) from dba_extents where tablespace_name = 'TEST' group by file_id;

   FILE_ID SUM(BLOCKS)
---------- -----------
         7        6408

SQL> alter table t1 allocate extent (size 30M);

Table altered.

SQL> select file_id, sum(blocks) from dba_extents where tablespace_name = 'TEST' group by file_id;

   FILE_ID SUM(BLOCKS)
---------- -----------
         8        1536
         7        8712
```